# Is it possible to get a larger square thumbnail from facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails

This gets me a small square FB thumbnail:
http://graph.facebook.com/5/picture?type=square

(UID example could be 5).

'd like a larger image (75 or 100px?) that is still cropped at the same points as the thumbnail. I know the param square can be large, but then it loses its crop positioning. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having a similar issue and went about solving it the hard way. This code will give you an imitation of a Facebook thumbnail in the largest possible size without losing resolution. Read more in the README.

https://github.com/bradley/Large-Profile-Thumbnails-for-Facebook-Developers

Comment: That's a really awesome script - good work! Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Just be careful because it can really hurt your server if you run this script on every load. Consider storing the actual URL of the user's thumbnail that facebook redirects to (i.e., NOT the graph url used to retrieve the thumb but the actual URL of the image) using CURL, and using it to check if the user has changed his or her image since the last time you did the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, square, small, normal and large

Try
 http://graph.facebook.com/5/picture?type=small
 http://graph.facebook.com/5/picture?type=normal
 http://graph.facebook.com/5/picture?type=large

Source : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
Go to pictures section.

Comment: I don't think you read my question correctly. Normal and Large don't crop the image into a square according to the user's specs.

Comment: Normal and large have specific width but not height.  Checkout the url above.  So you cant get square out of those normal and large.

Comment: This is actually a good link since FB now supports haight and width params, so you can have it large and square.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can specify a custom width and height!

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/shaverm/picture?width=60&height=150

Doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

Comment: Works awesome, much easier and better than the approved answer.